# DRV8301 driver IC for BLDC motor

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, stm32, power-electronics, motor-controller

I'm trying to build a BLDC ESC using stm32f405 and DRV8301. I'm able to generate PWM signals from STM32f405 but unable to detect the same PWM signals on the outputs of the DRV8301.I'm using a bench power supply and supplied upto 25V, Enabled the EN_GATE Pin. Please let me know if any other configurations have to be enabled to make the DRV8301 IC to work

Comment: At least post a schematics of your work.

Comment: Have you read the data sheet? Post the schematic you have used.